# How can i fetch all the address lookup table accounts created by an account(payer)?

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, solana-cli

For my particular use case i need to create an address lookup table for every user , I could not find any function that returns the address table created by an account(payer)

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the slot number when you create an Address Lookup Table,
later you can resolve the same address for the table to be able to fetch the Data

```
let [ix_table, table_address] = anchor.web3.AddressLookupTableProgram.createLookupTable({
            authority:  payer.publicKey,
            payer: payer.publicKey,
            recentSlot: slot
        });
```

if your table inited to fetch data use this  :

```
let lookupTableAccount = (await anchor.getProvider().connection.getAddressLookupTable(table_address)).value!;
```